# Is it possible to use COM smart pointers with the CList collection

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm attempting to create a CList with a COM smart pointer (one of the wrapper classes generated for `_com_ptr_t`) as the template parameter:

```
CList<IDispatchPtr, IDispatchPtr> list;
```

However I get several compilation errors similar to:

> `error C2664: 'void __stdcall SerializeElements(class CArchive &,class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct IDispatch,&struct __s_GUID _GUID_00020400_0000_0000_c000_00000000004
>   6> > *,int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'struct IDispatch ** ' to 'class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct IDispatch,&struct __s_GUID _GUID_00020400_0000_0000_c000_000000000046> > *'
>           Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

It compiles when using regular pointers:

```
CList<IDispatch*, IDispatch*> list;
```

Looking at the MFC code that calls SerializeElements it looks like the problem is that it takes a TYPE* and there's no conversion between `IDispatch** and IDispatchPtr*`.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way `operator&` is overloaded, you need to wrap the smart pointers in `CAdapt<>`:

```
CList<CAdapt<IDispatchPtr>, CAdapt<IDispatchPtr> > list;
```